# JSON to CSV in Python, CSV has more rows than JSON

Tags: python, json, csv

I am attempting to convert JSON into CSV using Python, but I'm encountering an issue where 2 lines of JSON are producing 6 lines of CSV. Here are samples of my original JSON and resulting CSV outputs:

JSON:

```
{ "_id" : "a1" ,"pl" : [ { "age" : 45, "n" : "ar"}, { "age" : 52, "n" : "Pi" }, { "age" : 18, "n" : "al"} ] , "ld" : 13}
{ "_id" : "a2" ,"pl" : [ { "age" : 85, "n" : "ta"}, { "age" : 46, "n" : "lee" }] , "ld" : 14}
```

CSV:

```
_id,  ld,  age,  n,  age,  n
a1,  13,  45,  ar,  45,  ar
a1,  13,  52,  Pi,  52,  Pi
a1,  13,  18,  al,  18,  al
a2,  14,  85,  ta,  85,  ta
a2,  14,  46,  lee,  46,  lee
```

I am currently processing 2 lines of JSON but unexpectedly receiving 5 lines of CSV output.

Below is the Python code I'm currently using:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

for i in glob.glob('D:\\1.json'):
    data = []
    df_it = pd.read_json(i, encoding='utf-8', lines=True, chunksize=100, dtype=object)
    for sub in df_it:
     data.append(sub)
    df = pd.concat(data)
    df = df.explode('pl')
    df = pd.concat([
        df.reset_index(drop=True),
        pd.json_normalize(df.pl),
    ], axis=1)
    df = df.drop(['pl', ], axis=1)
    df.to_csv('D:\\1.csv', index=None, encoding='utf-8')
```

I am hoping to get a CSV output formatted like this:

```
_id, pl.age1,  pl.n1,  pl.age2,  pl.n2, pl.age3,  pl.n3, ld, 
a1,    45,      ar,       52,     Pi,     18,      al,    13
a2,    85,      ta,       46,     lee,      ,        ,    14
```

What changes to my code or implementation do I need to make to achieve my desired CSV output?

Comment: Is your json stored in a single file (if so then the above json is wrong) or in different files (assuming with the use of glob)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the json are being stored in different files.

**Implementation:**

```py
import glob
from cherrypicker import CherryPicker
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
for index, file_name in enumerate(glob.glob("json/*.json")):
    with open(file_name, encoding="utf-8") as file:
        data = json.load(file)

    picker = CherryPicker(data)
    flat = picker.flatten().get()
    df = df._append(flat, ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv(f"output.csv", index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
_id,pl_0_age,pl_0_n,pl_1_age,pl_1_n,pl_2_age,pl_2_n,ld
a1,45,ar,52,Pi,18.0,al,13
a2,85,ta,46,lee,,,14
```

Comment: The code can work, provided that I perform some processing on JSON. Additionally, the output results will have an extra ". 0" tail at the end of each number. How can this be resolved?

Comment: That is because `int64` which is numpy int cannot handle `NaN` values so the default for numerical columns that have `NaN` are `float64`. You will have to do some processing before converting it into csv.
Since `int64` cannot handle `NaN` values I suggest you use `Int64` which is pandas int which can handle `NaN` values. You can find the documentation about this [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html).

Comment: `df["pl_2_age"] = df["pl_2_age"].astype("Int64")`